# Android create file in internal storage with world readable right

Tags: android, file, storage, permission-denied

I develop an application for Android.

I store files in internal storage with method :

```
getDir("myfolder", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE)
```

Then, I create a file :

```
File myFile = new File("myFile");
myFile.createNewFile();
```

But when I explorer my internal storage (with "File Explorer" or "ADB") I see that "myFile" is created but it doesn't have the same rights as "myFolder":

```
drwxrwxr-x app_88   app_88            2011-11-10 15:39 myFolder
-rw------- app_88   app_88          0 2011-11-10 15:39 myFile
```

In File API, I see "setReadable" method which can set readable right to me and world, but this methos is only for API level 9, and I am developing for API level 7 and more.

Here it's a problem because i don't have permission to read the file "myFile" thanks to ADB or File Explorer. I get error "Permission denied" and I don't want to "root" my device because of risks.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do the same on the file:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29 (available since API level 1)

HTH

Comment: Note that the file is stored in your application's `files` subdirectory; the same directory returned by `context.getFilesDir()`.